# How to update Preview.app from the command line without losing focus on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, updates, applescript, preview, focus

I want to update Preview.app in the background from the command line without losing focus of my current window. I know that I can use the following to open/update the view of a file, but then I lose focus to the Preview.app.

```
open -a Preview foo.pdf
```

I guess there might be some clever [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) commands to do so but so far I didn't find the right one.

Alternatively I would be interested into transfering the focus back to my current application directly after the update. I need this in order to update Preview.app's view of a PDF file through a vi autocmd after I update the PDF file according to changes in a [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) file I am editing. Here is an example of what I want to achieve but using [Ubuntu and evince](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=615157).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile i was told the solution by a nice person called Guillermo commenting on my [blog](http://phacker.org/2010/03/26/automate-pdf-preview-when-using-vi-to-edit-latex-on-osx/). The solution is to use:

```
open -g -a Preview foo.pdf
```

to update the pdf in the background.

Comment: Nice. After you posted your question I experimented a bit with AppleScript, as "all" it takes for Preview to update an open document is just give it focus. (Like: open a PDF, change it using some other program, and then go back to Preview: it will update it right away.) Hence, no need to manually reload the document by calling `open`, if one could just, somehow, fool Preview into thinking it has focus. But I did NOT find any solution. (Even more, I discovered that Preview is not that easily scripted, if at all...)

Comment: If I try this on Lion the PDF still isn't updated until it gets focus. Any idea how to fix it? (BTW: Your blog gives an error)

Comment: doesn't work for me either (Lion)

Comment: I just tested on Lion and you are correct preview does not show the new content until focused. So this solution does not work in Lion.

Answer (score 1):

The is a rather old thread. I don't know whether you can do this 10 years ago. But currently you only have to `open -g xxx.pdf`